# Accessing properties of user document from mongodb , mongoose, and typescript

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, types

I m trying to understand why I cannot access certain properties from a user doc. When querying the DB for a user doc, I would like to access its properties.

My User model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
});

export default mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
```

The query:

```
const user = User.findById(payload.sub);
const { email } = user;
```

This is the typescript error I get:

```
Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Query<(IUser & { _id: ObjectId; }) | null, IUser & { _id: ObjectId; }, {}, IUser>'.
```

I fail to understand why I get this error. I also can't seem to access the _id property.

Comment: `user` is a PromiseLike. You have to `await` for it to resolve first.

Comment: thank you! solved the issue. Would you like to add your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying a database is an asynchronous process. Mongoose will actually not return a Promise directly, but its own class that extends Promise. However, you can still use `await` to wait for it to resolve:

```
const user = await User.findById(payload.sub);

if (!user) { /* ??? */ } // no user found

const { email } = user;
```

You should also check if the user exists, since this method can also return `null` if no such user was found.